# style a taskbar in html with css is getting me mad

Tags: html, css

I'm getting mad with my css.. I want to get the following Structure

```
<div class="taskbar">
  <div class="startbutton">
    Text
  </div>
  <div class="tasks">
    <div class="task">task 1</div>
    <div class="task">task 2</div>
    <div class="task">task 3</div>
     ...
  </div>
<div>
```

Where the following criterias meet:

-`taskbar` should pe placed on the screen bottom (`position:absolute?`)

-`startbutton` should be left (width dynamic to content text)

-`tasks` should take the rest of the window width

-`task` should have a `min-width and max-width`... depending of window width, the width can be variable between min and max-width.

The problem with the dynamic task width is no problem. i will solve that with jquery on resize event... But the rest is getting me mad!!!
I'm not posting any css content to not leed into you into my wrong direction :-(

Thanks for reply...

Update: Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XjYVD/1/

Comment: Put up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you've put together till now.

Comment: Dear Without your CSS, we cant help you any more. so plz produce in Jsfiddle with your Amaziiiiiiiiing CSS

Comment: here we are... http://jsfiddle.net/XjYVD/1/ my problems: -the task should have something like margin-top... -the tasks should not wrap around

Comment: @TheVillain What's your desired result?

Comment: Creating a Taskbar with Width:100%, a Startbutton (width defined by content), and a tasks area with a dynamic count of tasks. Each task should have a minwidth and a maxwidth. Depending on the count of tasks the width of the task can be smaller than the maxwidth but at least the minwidth (overflow:ellipsis). The complete taskbar should not wrap arround and also the tasks should stay in a single line. I think the math of setting the actual size of the tasks is not the problem. This can be a jquery task when the rest of the taskbar behave like it should..

Comment: @TheVillain :  i think this is something what you want :http://jsfiddle.net/XjYVD/3/

Comment: Great Era... Very simple and just working. I modified it ab bit and here is my current solution http://jsfiddle.net/d5pUu/. I will try to work with this... Thanks so far..